# PHP Header Filename Not Working In Chrome

Tags: php

For some reason, Chrome seems to ignore the following PHP header:

```
header("Content-Disposition: inline; attachment; filename=\"somefile.xlsx\"");
```

The name of the file that gets downloaded is the name of the script that serves the file. It works fine in Safari.

My complete method is:

```
static function loadFile($path, $noFileName = false) {
    $mime = mime_content_type($path);
    $pathInfo = pathInfo($path);
    $name = $pathInfo["basename"];
    $size = filesize($path);
    
    header("Content-type: $mime");
    
    if (!$noFileName) {
        header("Content-Disposition: inline; attachment; filename=\"$name\"");
    }
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");

    header("Accept-Ranges: bytes");
    header("Content-Length: $size");
            
    readfile($path);
}
```

How can I get it to work in Chrome? Also, when right-clicking on the download link in Safari, I have the option of downloading the linked file. In Chrome, it just has "Save Link". Is there anything I can do about that?

Comment: "inline" and "attachment" are two different possible values for the "Content-Disposition" header, but you're providing both of them; is that just a mistake?

Comment: Regarding your second question, "Save Link" and "Download" are probably just different names for the same thing: "fetch the content at this URL, and save it to a file on disk". Remember that from the browser's point of view, *every* page you view is being "downloaded", so "save" is a _technically_ more accurate label for "put it somewhere permanent on disk, rather than showing it on screen immediately".

Comment: `it just has "Save Link"`...and did you try that and see what it does? What do you think the difference is between that and the "download link" button? I'd say it's probably just different wording for the same thing. But yeah, it might be ignoring the content-disposition header because it's malformed - you can't specify both inline and attachment at the same time.

Comment: Removing attachment took care of the naming problem. However, for "Save Link As...", For some reason, Chrome saves the source of the web page instead of downloading the linked file. Since the naming problem has been resolved, I'm not too concerned about the "Save As" not working. Thanks for the help!

Comment: If the link goes to a script which does nothing except download a file, then Save Link As would download whatever that script returns - i.e. a file. If the script could possibly sometimes return HTML, it's possible that is what happened, potentially